# How to convert the elasticsearch query to aggregationbuilder

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-5

I am trying to write a query using elasticsearch where response should be sum of a column with condition of other fields. I'm able to do it using elasticsearch query but unable to do is using elasticsearch aggregationbuilder in elasticsearch api. Anyone please help me to write the code in elasticsearch api same like below attached query?

```
{
   "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match": {
            "customerId": "13b7e2e8-8bf0-435b-b7f7-949c2e69b1d7"
          }
        }
      ],
      "must_not": [
        {
          "match": {
            "state": "Cancelled"
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": []
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "totalStakes": {
      "sum": {
        "field": "totalStake"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I have tried the below code but it's not working as expected.

```
AggregationBuilder sumOfTotalStake = AggregationBuilders.sum("totalStake").field("totalStake");
        BoolQueryBuilder bqb = boolQuery().mustNot(termQuery("state", "Cancelled").must(termQuery("customerId", "13b7e2e8-8bf0-435b-b7f7-949c2e69b1d7")));
        // create the filter aggregation and add the sub-aggregation
        FilterAggregationBuilder aggregation = AggregationBuilders.filter("totalStakes", bqb)
                .subAggregation(sumOfTotalStake);
```

Expected result sould be below format :

```
{
  "took": 3,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "skipped": 0,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 10,
    "max_score": 4.3412046,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "totalStakes": {
      "value": 65579
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: are you using java api ? which version of ES API ?

Comment: <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
  <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
  <version>6.4.3</version>
and
<groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-data-elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.5.RELEASE</version>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use below code in java. This code is in ES 7.X version but same or with minor change it will work.

```java
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();

BoolQueryBuilder qb = QueryBuilders.boolQuery()
                .must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("customerId", "13b7e2e8-8bf0-435b-b7f7-949c2e69b1d7"))
                .mustNot(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("state", "Cancelled"));

searchSourceBuilder.query(qb);

AggregationBuilder ab = AggregationBuilders.sum("totalStakes").field("totalStake");
searchSourceBuilder.aggregation(ab);

searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = client.search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
```

**Updated:**

you can set `size` param to `0` for getting your expected result. You can keep above code as it and it will return only aggregation output.

```java
searchSourceBuilder.size(0);
```

Comment: Can I use filter when creating the AggregationBuilder  object? Can you please check my updated description in the main post?

Comment: yes, you can use that because `filter` will go to `BoolQueryBuilder` and not `AggregationBuilder` builder.

Comment: In my existing code I have NativeSearchQueryBuilder object where I want to add the AggregationBuilder with the condition filter.

Comment: Can you please help me to write that filter with the above condition which will return the sum of a column? @Sagar Patel

Comment: do you want to just get aggregation result right ?

Comment: yes I want aggregate result only.
I have NativeSearchQueryBuilder objetc which are returning list of object with different state. I want those result as it is. Only changes require to Aggregationbuilder with sum of which state does not Cancelled.

Comment: @DebasishHalder Please check my updated answer.